# Geometric power series

Tags: power-series

I've been stuck on the following question for a while now, where i have to use the geometric series to expand the following function into a power series at the given centre, and ﬁnd the radius of convergence, which is;

$$\frac1{1+x}\text{ about }x_0=2$$

I have managed to take 1/3 out and then have attempted to use the ratio test, which i think is the right approach but i can't seem to get a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \frac1{1+x}
&=& \displaystyle \frac1{3+(x-2)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac13 \dfrac1{1+\frac{x-2}3} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac13 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{x-2}3\right)^n \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac13 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac13\right)^n (x-2)^n \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to rewrite that fraction to look like the sum of a geometric series, i.e., $\frac{1}{1-r}$, and we need for $r$ to somehow be in terms of $(x-2)$. Thus:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+x} &= \frac{1}{3+x-2}\\
&= \frac{1}{3--(x-2)}\\
&=\frac33\cdot\frac{\frac13}{1-\left(-\frac{x-2}{3}\right)}\\
&=\frac13\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{x-2}{3}\right)}
\end{align}$$

Now it's in the right form, so we can write it as a geometric series:

$$\frac1{1+x}=\frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{x-2}{3}\right)^n=\frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n(x-2)^n$$

Does that make sense?